# How is the "HiVal" value determined for the Hi-Lo algorithm in NHibernate?

Tags: confluence, hilo

What is the current value that Atlassian Confluence is using for their "HiVal"-value for the Hi-Lo algorithm in NHibernate?

Is this a hard-coded value, or is it determined algorithmically? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The HiVal is recalculated in Confluence dynamically, based on the existing persisted HiVal in the table.  If you have own a commercial license for Confluence, you can download the source code and look at `com.atlassian.hibernate.extras.ResettableTableHiLoGenerator` to see the algorithm.